# android.process.acore stopped - CM10 on Galaxy S3

Tags: cyanogenmod

I'm getting the error "android.process.acore has stopped" constantly, which makes my phone impossible to use. I have cm-10.2.0 on a galaxy S3. I have already tried factory reset and re-flashing the ROM several times. Any more ideas or is my phone now a brick?

Comment: If it were a brick, you could not flash it. Are you sure the ROM you've flashed was intended for your S3? Maybe you try a different ROM (of course one for the S3)?

Comment: "brick" metaphorically. I cannot use the phone for anything. I'm pretty sure it was the right ROM, I copied it twice with adb push and flashed it twice.

Comment: Maybe your download was broken. I'd try with a different one. Besides: though you've mentioned factory-reset (which should have done that), have you wiped `/data` and `/cache` prior to flashing? Also worth a try.

Comment: yeah i've wiped everything I could. I'll try with a new file and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Tried downloading a new image of CM10, which I am able to flash but it does not solve the problem. I also tried to flash CM11, which fails with error "status 7".

Comment: Maybe you take a look at [these questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=android.process.acore+has+stopped+answers%3A1) (and their answers) then – hopefully they shed some light.

Comment: thanks but I've already done extensive reasearch online. These links just tell me to do a factory reset.

Comment: OK, then I'm out, sorry. Hopefully someone else might have another idea...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that google restores faulty contacts each time you did a factory reset? deactivate google sync for contacts and delete data for contacts and contact storage. This will delete all your contacts so make a backup!

*(sorry I meant to write this in the comments section... now I don't know how to delete this.)*